# How to open file with admin, edit and save using bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I create a bat file to open a specific file (hosts) with administrator, edit it and save?

I tried it, but it isn't working:

```
echo C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts >> 192.168.100.9       dev.rw1.local
echo C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts >> 192.168.100.10       wiki.rw1.local
```

I tried too using it directly on CMD and in a CMD oppened as Admin and didn't work

Comment: What is your purpose ? Did you want to edit the hosts file and add some lines there and save it with a batch file ?

Comment: Can you post the batch file that you've tried writing yourself?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Hackoo, yes, it's what i'm trying to

Comment: @QueenSvetlana, I didn't find how can I do it, that's why I came here

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Hackoo I edited my question

Comment: Check if your hosts file is not readonly ! and what did mean by "didn't work" ? you mean no lines are added on your hosts file, or did you got any other errors ?

Comment: @Hackoo it isn't read only. "Didn't work" mean that didn't added lines to file.

Comment: Check my answer below and tell me if it is working now or not for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Color 9A & Mode con cols=83 lines=5
Title %~n0 Add some lines on hosts files
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                      **************************************
ECHO                       Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                      **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

set "hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

FIND /C /I "dev.rw1.local" "%hostspath%" >nul
FIND /C /I "wiki.rw1.local" "%hostspath%" >nul


IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" (
    Attrib -R %hostspath%
    (
        echo(
        echo ###############################################
        echo # Lines added by "%username%" #
        echo 192.168.100.9       dev.rw1.local
        echo 192.168.100.10      wiki.rw1.local
        echo ###############################################
    )>> "%hostspath%"
) 

Attrib +R "%hostspath%"
```

Comment: In general, there should not be a space between the variable name and value. Perhaps this works here, but should it be this way?. `set params = %*:"=""`